# webelemnet location with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have below html. I want to get group of `<li>` and locate each.

```
<div id="shiplist" class="vertical slide" data-interval="false">
<div class="<inner ship-list-container">
    <div class="item active">
        <ul class="unstyled ship-list">
            <li class="selected"></li>
            <li>
                <a href="....">
                    XXXX
                    <span class="small">
                          xxx
            <li>
```

My current code:

```
ItemList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner ship-list-container']//div[@class='item']//ul/li")
for item in ItemList :
    print　item.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="small"]').text　　　
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="carousel-inner ship-list-container"]//div[@class="item active"]//ul/li[' + str(i) + ']/a').click()
```

When I capture the `span class="small"` through below code, it's wrong

```
print item.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="small"]').text
```

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ; Stacktrace:

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue this way:

```
ItemList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner ship-list-container']//div[@class='item']//ul/li")
for x in range(len(ItemList)):
    print　ItemList[x].find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="small"]').text　　　
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="carousel-inner ship-list-container"]//div[@class="item active"]//ul/li[' + str(i) + ']/a').click()
    ItemList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner ship-list-container']//div[@class='item']//ul/li")
```

Comment: Thanks. But I found the result of "Print ItemList[x]....." are always the first item . The actual result should have several different text, but the it only show the first item

Answer (score 0):

Thank Richard.

My html

```
        <li>
            <a href="....">
                XXXX
                <span class="small">
                      X1
        <li>
        <li>
            <a href="....">
                XXXX
                <span class="small">
                      X2
        <li>
```

When I use following code

```
ItemList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='inner ship-list-container']//div[@class='item']//ul/li") 
for x in range(len(ItemList)):
    print　ItemList[x].find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="small"]').text
```

here

The Result only show the first item
    X1
    X1